# Displaying data results from fetch to HTML

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am trying to present a list of calculated results from a local server. On the console the data appears as an array of objects but on the page it is displayed as separated string characters for each li. How can i display the each objects content in each li?

here is what the console logs:

[{"number":11,"result":89,"createdDate":1581587946359,"_id":"4yS9mgRDE1LoBoyF"},{"number":12,"result":144,"createdDate":1645041579497,"_id":"HoFmbQrx1fgvChUH"},{"number":30,"result":832040,"createdDate":1581587975438,"_id":"KUonsyueRqD78mSv"},{"number":12,"result":144,"createdDate":1644936618090,"_id":"SY5oVvt6Go2Ivsql"},{"number":3,"result":2,"createdDate":1645015992250,"_id":"UuFkzs48RMkzySGW"},{"number":12,"result":144,"createdDate":1644935649784,"_id":"Wx3UgQ5bghSnGJqv"}]

```
  const list = document.getElementById("list");

  fetch(resultURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const calcResults = JSON.stringify(data.results);

      console.log(calcResults);
      for (let i = 0; i < calcResults.length; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = calcResults[i];
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
    });
}
window.addEventListener("load", fibonacci);
```

Comment: Please show us the console output of the results

Comment: JSON.stringify is making it a string again, then looping though each char, remove that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `calcResults` is a string, not an object.  Use `data.results` instead.

From the looks of it, your results are in the document shape: { results: Result[] }, so the `data` from the fetch contains a document that has a `results` member.

You already called json() to convert your object to an object, so the heavy lifting has been done.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = data.results[i];
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

As a side note, if you log `data.results` instead of stringifying it, your debug window will let you expand/collapse.

```js
console.log(data.results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue. Your are appending the complete object to DOM. Instead you need to append the values of Object to DOM. Look below example, I appended the result of calculation `data[i].result`, you can do this way any values.

```js
var data = [{"number":11,"result":89,"createdDate":1581587946359,"_id":"4yS9mgRDE1LoBoyF"},{"number":12,"result":144,"createdDate":1645041579497,"_id":"HoFmbQrx1fgvChUH"},{"number":30,"result":832040,"createdDate":1581587975438,"_id":"KUonsyueRqD78mSv"},{"number":12,"result":144,"createdDate":1644936618090,"_id":"SY5oVvt6Go2Ivsql"},{"number":3,"result":2,"createdDate":1645015992250,"_id":"UuFkzs48RMkzySGW"},{"number":12,"result":144,"createdDate":1644935649784,"_id":"Wx3UgQ5bghSnGJqv"},{"number":5,"result":5,"createdDate":1623234311998,"_id":"XT2rgLbEQC5ADC2J"},{"number":4,"result":3,"createdDate":1644936028242,"_id":"YXmMmbYvrekHQar4"},{"number":8,"result":21,"createdDate":1623234317407,"_id":"b5M24lLggweXY24L"},{"number":10,"result":55,"createdDate":1581587938016,"_id":"itAGET6wHw6wcxfN"},{"number":11,"result":89,"createdDate":1645015996622,"_id":"jD3M4opGHCmS7yiM"},{"number":6,"result":8,"createdDate":1644935779049,"_id":"jFFWDD6ir6U2Z4pH"},{"number":12,"result":144,"createdDate":1644936046931,"_id":"jG2G6GoP9ZJRMNim"},{"number":5,"result":5,"createdDate":1644935775114,"_id":"xu1oairIRQbE19G1"}]

  const list = document.getElementById("list");

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = data[i].result;
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because your using `JSON.stringify` instead of `JSON.parse`.
So you are basically looping over a string and when you reference `calcResults[i]` you'll get the character at that index of the string.

You need to call `JSON.parse(data.result)` in order to convert the string to a
JS object. Then you can loop over the objects of the JS Array.

If your local server uses a JSON body parser, however, you actually
don't need to call `JSON.parse` the result.

Comment: The OP is using the Fetch API, which provides the `response.json()` method, which parses the JSON (and is already present in the code the OP shows). No need for another round of parsing. Also, this is taking place on the browser, so whether the server has a JSON body parser or not is irrelevant.